How to use Istio to perform HTTP to GRPC trans-coding?
Currently I have a react based frontend web app and several backend services which perform gRPC calls. The frontend app needs to communicate with the backends and it requires HTTP to grpc trans-coding. Currently I am using envoy proxy to achieve this and it is working fine.
Now I want to migrate this application to another GKE cluster which has Istio mesh configured in it. How can I achieve the same HTTP <--> grpc translation using Istio objects? Do we use Virtual service + envoyfilter here? How can we debug these objects?
I tried creating Virtual service + envoyfilters in istio similar to the existing envoy proxy config, but I am not sure if I have done it right, I am also not sure how to debug or view logs if the envoyfilter is performing the translation correctly.
